# Пшеница и пшено

Tags: однокоренные-слова

И снова я о похожих словах.
Есть злак пшеница. Зерно пшеницы, соответственно, тоже пшеница. А есть другой злак - просо. Но его зерна почему-то называются пшено.
А почему так? Какая связь между пшеницей и зернами проса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Пшеница" происходит от "пшено" (см. в сл. Фасмера), а "пшено" (что сделано?) — это страдательное причастие прошлого времени от "пихать", буквально — "толчённый (злак)". Вероятно, потом произошло сужение смысла слова "пшено", и оно стало обозначать зерно конкретного злака (проса).

Comment: Надо же! Никогда бы не подумала!  
Спасибо большое за ответ!